# Weird growth on wisteria stem

Tags: flowers, diseases

See attached picture. Is this growth normal?  If not, what do I do?

[image]

Comment: Hi! Is the rest of the plant healthy?

Comment: Yes the rest of the plant looks fine as far as I can tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had my gardener cut off the abnormal growth and the plant seems to be doing fine over the last month.  No new growth detected on the plant so far.  Much simpler option rather than to remove the plant or move it elsewhere

Answer (score 7):

I think it is crown gall, a bacterial infection.

Probably your best course of action is to carefully remove the plant from where it is growing, before the disease spreads to some other, and possibly more valuable plants you may have.

Since crown gall is caused by is a soil borne bacterium, you might avoid planting anything in its place for a couple of years.

Comment: Annuals would probably be OK for a while. I've never seen the bacteria hit daisies or celosia. *Agrobacterium tumefaciens* is now *Rhizobium radiobacter*, AKA *Agrobacterium radiobacter* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrobacterium_tumefaciens I hope they're finally done with the name changing.

Comment: You are correct @WayfaringStranger. I should have said "... avoid planting **any susceptible species** in its place ..."